# Why is my memory consumption going up every time I query mnesia?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

Every time I issue a query, some of my memory gets eaten, and is never recovered. If I issue the *same* query, more memory is used up.

For example, if I issue this query (and later convert records to maps):

```
CatchAll = [{'_', [], ['$_']}],
mnesia:dirty_select(read_store, CatchAll)
```

*Edit: sorry the image was completely wrong - it was showing processes not queries*

Comment: What language? Can you force the GC (provided it uses one)? Else, it might be a leak in their part.

Comment: Erlang. I don't think I can force it...

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about Erlang. If it uses a GC though, there's probably some way to force it to run. Worth a try.

Comment: How big is your table? Are you reading from disc copy or from ram copy? Please provide further information

Comment: disk + ram. The problem was storing large strings in each record. Fixed for now with storing binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was storing strings instead of binaries in mnesia tables.

The result of http request is a string:

`httpc:request(get, {Url,[]}, [{timeout, ?TIMEOUT}], [])`

However, it is possible to change it to a binary instead:

`httpc:request(get, {Url,[]}, [{timeout, ?TIMEOUT}], [{body_format, binary}])`

This reduced the memory footprint by at least a factor of 20.

Comment: Worked for me.  I was importing a set of CSV files and run out of memory.  Changed my CSV importer to convert strings to binary and problem went away.  Thank you very much.